# contour detection: reduce glare on image opencv/python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on contour detection for the image below, however due to the lightning condition, the detection is not complete where the image displays glares. I am trying to remove them in order to get a better contour detection.

Here is the original image

[image: image with glare]

And here is the grayed + thresholded image on which the cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats is ran to detect the objects. I have boxed the areas where I need to reduce exposure. (since I am using an inverse THRESH_BINARY_INV filter those areas appear black).

[image: grayed + thresholded image]

As you can see hereafter the object detected areas are incomplete, the cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats will not detect the complete area for the object

[image: Object areas]

And then of course the contour itself which is calculated on the cropped outlined component is wrong as well:

[image: Cropped outlined]

So of course the contour itself is wrong:

[image: Wrong contour due to glare]

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def getFilteredContours(image, minAreaFilter=20000) -> np.array:
    ret = []
    ctrs,_ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    for i, c in enumerate(ctrs):
        # Calculate the area of each contour
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area < minAreaFilter:
            break
        ret.append(c)
    return ret

birdEye = cv2.imread(impath)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(birdEye, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
threshImg = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
(numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(
    threshImg, 4, cv2.CV_32S)

#then for each identified component we extract the component and get the contour

filteredIdx = getFilteredLabelIndex(stats)

for labelId in filteredLabelId:
    componentMask = (labels == i).astype("uint8") * 255
    ctrs, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    ctr = max(ctrs, key=cv2.contourArea)    
    cv2.drawContours(birdEye, [cntrs], -1, (255, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow("original contour", birdEye)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions would be welcome,

Thanks

Pat

Comment: Contour detection function takes a binary image as input. Do you know how can you obtain a binary image?

Comment: Yes, indeed I have updated my question

Comment: I suggest you look into diffuse lighting so that your images have reduced glare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [floodFill](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0) for filling the background first.

`cv2.floodFill` gives good result applying your sample image.
Result is good because the background is relatively homogenous.
`floodFill` uses the color information, opposed to other algorithms that use only the brightness.
The background has a slight brightness gradient that "flood fill" algorithm handles well.

You may use the following stages:

- Replace all (dark) values (below 10 for example) with 10 - avoiding issues where there are black pixels inside an object.
- Use `cv2.floodFill` for filling the background with black color.
  Use the top left corner as a "background" seed color (assume pixel [10,10] is not in an object).
- Convert to Grayscale.
- Apply threshold - convert all pixels above zero to 255.
- Use opening (morphological operation) for removing small outliers.
- Find contours.

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

birdEye = cv2.imread(r"C:\Rotem\tools.jpg")

# Replace all (dark) values below 10 with 10 - avoiding issues where there are black pixels inside an object
birdEye = np.maximum(birdEye, 10)

foreground = birdEye.copy()

seed = (10, 10)  # Use the top left corner as a "background" seed color (assume pixel [10,10] is not in an object).

# Use floodFill for filling the background with black color
cv2.floodFill(foreground, None, seedPoint=seed, newVal=(0, 0, 0), loDiff=(5, 5, 5, 5), upDiff=(5, 5, 5, 5))

# Convert to Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(foreground, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Use opening for removing small outliers
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5)))

# Find contours
cntrs, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Draw contours
cv2.drawContours(birdEye, cntrs, -1, (255, 0, 255), 3)

# Show images for testing
cv2.imshow('foreground', foreground)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('birdEye', birdEye)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`foreground`:
[image: foreground]

`birdEye` output:
[image: birdEye output]

Comment: That looks awesome, is there a way to smoothen the contours ? they look a bit rough. What about the parasite contour down and on the right of your image, can I filter that out ?

Comment: Hmm something strange here I ran you code as is and my foreground image does not look black. Did you miss something ?

Comment: Strange... Sometimes a posted image gets modified. Try downloading the image from your post, and use it as an input.

Comment: The parasite contour is black in the original image. We can crop it out, or mask it.

Comment: Smoothing the edges could be challenging. Morphological operations may help

Comment: My bad, the image I used had an external border. Now everything works as you suggested. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using dilation and erosion function(or closing function) in cv2.

If you use `cv2.dilate` function, white area is bigger than now.

Conversely, if you use `cv2.erode` function, white area is smaller than now.

This iteration remove noise of black area.

Closing function is dilation followed by erosion.

See `https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html`